# Rotation to a specific angle not working

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation

I have a image of a cartoon face to rotate it just like as shaking head a little bit from left to right (as we do when hearing music) for a  specific duration of time like 5-7 seconds. So, i am doing the following:

```
-(void)rotation{

CABasicAnimation *rotate = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
[rotate setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0]];
[rotate setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:45]];
[rotate setDuration:5.0];
[rotate setAutoreverses:YES];
[rotate setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];

[[faceImage layer] addAnimation:rotate forKey:@"dangleFaceImage"];

}
```

But the image is spinning like a ball! I think my code is not correct at all. How can i do that rotation?

Comment: Ever heard of [radians](http://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian)? The documentation mention that all angles are in radians all over the place (like "rotates by 'angle' radians")

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will have work on setting the anchor point of the layer. Place the anchor point of the layer containing the face at the lower mid bottom. The rotation will then take place from this point. Then it will appear that the head is tilting from the neck.

Comment: First understand the last line of his question and then down vote.

Comment: I dont have enough reputations to vote u up! So, sorry if anyone voted u down. But u got my point. But i cant understand how can i do it in code. can u show any example?

Comment: In CALayer.h
anchorPoint - Defines the anchor point of the layer's bounds rectangle. Animatable.

@property CGPoint anchorPoint

Lets say you have a calayer as head

headLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(headLayer.bounds.size.width/2, headLayer.bounds.size.height);


this will bring the anchor point to lower mid bottom.

Now, if you apply the rotation animation, then the center will be this point in it.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 2):

rotation takes value in radians, not degree.

```
[rotate setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat: 45*M_PI/180.]];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But the problem is it is rotating like lower position is moving respect to the upper position. But i need to move the upper position of the image in respect to the lower position of the image! & also moving to one side not in the both side!

Answer (score 0):

For Leftside

```
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(imgBg.transform, M_PI/-360);
    imgBg.transform = transform;
```

For right side

```
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(imgBg.transform, M_PI/360);
    imgBg.transform = transform;
```

Comment: here you can adjust your angle

Answer (score 0):

Try to rotate by using rotation transform. You have to set your image to an ImageView first. Assume it is faceImageView then

```
faceImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(faceImageView.transform, angle);
```

It will rotate to desired angle :)

Answer (score 0):

In CALayer.h
anchorPoint - Defines the anchor point of the layer's bounds rectangle. Animatable.

```
@property CGPoint anchorPoint
```

Lets say you have a calayer as headLayer

```
headLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(headLayer.bounds.size.width/2,headLayer.bounds.size.height);
```

this will bring the anchor point to lower mid bottom.

Now, if you apply the rotation animation, then the center will be this point in it.